# DI with WinRT ComObject support

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, windows-store-apps, unity-container, c++-cx

I just tried to use Unity DI for, well, basic DI. Here is my setup:

**C# Component project**

```
public interface ILanguageBindings { ... }
```

**C++/CX Component project**

```
private ref class LanguageBindings : ILanguageBindings { ... }


public ref class LanguageImplementation {
public:
    ILanguageBindings GetLanguageBindings();
}
```

**C# Portable**

```
public class Bootstrap {
    private UnityContainer container;

    public void Initialize(ILanguageBindings language) {
        this.container.RegisterInstance<ILanguageBindings>(language);
    }
}
```

**C# App**

```
var languageImpl = new LanguageImplementation();
var languageBindings = languageImpl.GetLanguageBindings();
var bootstrap = new Bootstrap();

bootstrap.Initialize(languageBindings);
```

I get the following error message from UnityContainer:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The type System.__ComObject cannot be 
assigned to variables of type SparkiyEngine.Bindings.Language.ILanguageBindings.
```

I'm using `3.5.1405-prerelease` version (the one that works on both Windows and Windows Phone). Is there a way to make this to work with Unity container since I'm using it in the rest of the project. If not, what are alternatives that support ComObjects?

Full code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Sparkiy/sparkiy-client/tree/development), I just pushed the problematic code.

Comment: The ones that did down vote me, can you please say why? I asked the question, searched for solutions and gave you example of error... What more can you ask for?

Comment: http://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/565054 I used recipe from there - downgrade unity to version 3. Not sure that this solution is valid for WinRT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing

```
private ref class LanguageBindings : ILanguageBindings { ... }
```

to

```
public ref class LanguageBindings sealed : ILanguageBindings { ... }
```